# chrome modify response body cors

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a Chrome extension can modify response.

Because webRequest can't modify response directly, so I redirect a `data://` .

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  function (details) {
    return {
      redirectUrl: 'data:application/javascript;charset=utf-8,' + xxx
    }
  },
  {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
  ["blocking"]
)
```

It's work successly.

But, once cross domain， It's error.

I tried to add this:

```
chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(
  function (details) {

  const url = details.url

    if(details.type == 'xmlhttprequest') {
        details.responseHeaders.push({"name":"Access-Control-Allow-Origin","value": "*"})
        details.responseHeaders.push({"name":"Access-Control-Allow-Credentials","value":"true"})
     }

     return {responseHeaders:details.responseHeaders};
  },
  {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
  ["responseHeaders","blocking"]
)
```

But show :

**The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is '' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. Origin 'http://www.tryied.com' is therefore not allowed access.**

Now, I'm comfuse that how can I fixed?

Comment: This seems like a problem of CORS. Check the [Cross-Origin XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr) documentation for reference. You'll be adding your domain in the permissions property in your manifest file.

Comment: @noogui i tried also error